# Related spring dependencies in pom maven dependency file

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I recently upgraded my spring-boot in my application from version 1.5.x to 2.2.0, during this process I had to add / upgrade many dependencies. Some of them are mentioned below :

```
spring-data-jpa
spring-aspects
spring-beans
spring-context-support
spring-expression
spring-jdbc
spring-messagin
spring-orm
spring-tx
spring-webmvc
```

All of the above spring artifacts previously had version 4.x (checked from dependency:tree) now I upgraded all of them to 5.2.1. I had to add all of them to my `pom.xml` file. **Entries for these dependencies were not present before.** Is there any way to replace them with one dependency (as they are closely related) or reduce the number of entries ?

Comment: Have you checked out the spring-boot-starters? See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters

Comment: @anand1st Are you suggesting me to replace all the above spring dependecies with spring-boot-starters ?

Comment: I believe if you add spring-boot-starter-data-jpa and spring-boot-starter-web, most of the dependencies would have been taken care off. I'm assuming you have already added spring-boot-dependencies in your dependencyManagement with version=2.2.0.RELEASE, type=pom and scope=import.

Comment: Yes , @anand1st I was missing on that part. I upgraded my version of dependencies in dependencyManagement and I didn't removed the above mentioned dependencies ,  and everything worked fine.